# forward fill method fills extended rows

Tags: pandas

Forward fill method overwrites 'NA' values from original file.
Is there any way to treat "NA" literally instead of converting it to NaN while reading a file?

```
!wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/datameetgeo/sample.txt

import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('sample.txt', sep='\t')
df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

As can be seen in the above example, The value of "C-54465" is carried forward to next college code 954. It is wrong and it should be limited to first 22 rows.
Is there any way to control how ffill works or how "NA" values are treaded while reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `pd.read_csv` interprets `NA` as null.  You can turn this off with the parameter `keep_default_na=False`

```
pd.read_csv('sample.txt', sep='\t', keep_default_na=False)
```

Comment: @shantanuo I answered your question and showed how to control how NA is treated while reading from a csv. If you have a concrete example, we can remove ambiguity.